# Angularjs: Set form to dirty on model change from outside angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polyfills

I'm having a peculiar case on my hands. I'm using the number-polyfill for `input[type="number"]` in my Angular app. Now, the problem with that is that it's doesn't take into accound Angularjs's way of handling things.

Like, if I increment/decrement the input value programatically, the ngModel associated with the input does not get the updated value.

I've resolved that by writing a custom directive, and passing the model into the pollyfill

```
angular.module('appModule').
  directive('type', ['$parse', '$timeout', function($parse, $timeout) {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function($scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModel) {
      ...
      if iAttrs.type is 'number'
        iElement.inputNumber(ngModel)  // <-- THIS LINE
      ...
    }
  }
```

In the polyfill code, I've modified this:

```
increment = function(elem) {
  ...
  if (model != null) {
    model.$setViewValue(newVal);
  }
  ...
}
```

which works perfectly. Now, the problem is that **even after updating the model's value, the associated form does not become dirty**. In my code, it's **not possible** to pass the form as an argument into this polyfill.

I tried using `model.$dirty = true`, but that's not working.

Any other way?

Comment: What do you mean by `[Advanced]` in title?

Comment: didn't know how to distinguish it from the (rather common) query of updating the form's state. Updated the title now.

Comment: Calling `$setViewValue` should set your form control to dirty. Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Oh, I figured out the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the error. Although the `$setViewValue` should have set my form to dirty, the thing which was stopping it was the fact that the code where I was doing this was `out-of-$scope` ;)

And, for that the [`$scope.$apply()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) comes in handy. So, now along with the model, I'm also passing in the $scope to the polyfill.

```
angular.module('appModule').
  directive('type', ['$parse', '$timeout', function($parse, $timeout) {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function($scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModel) {
      ...
      if iAttrs.type is 'number'
        iElement.inputNumber(ngModel, $scope)  // <-- THIS LINE
      ...
    }
  }

increment = function(elem) {
  ...
  if (model != null) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      model.$setViewValue(newVal);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could share your modifications to number-polyfill?

Comment: @schmod: The changes are what I've written in my answer. If you would like the full changed file, let me know...